# Уменьшить размер bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

У меня проект с двумя страницами, десяток компонентов и контэйнеров.

При сборке проекта bundle.js весит 6 МБ. Я считаю, что это много. Потому что на мобильном страница достаточно долго грузится.

Результаты прикрепил к теме BundleAnalyzerPlugin.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'server',
            analyzerHost: 'localhost',
            analyzerPort: 8888,
            reportFilename: 'report.html',
            defaultSizes: 'parsed',
            openAnalyzer: true,
            generateStatsFile: false,
            statsFilename: 'stats.json',
            statsOptions: null,
            logLevel: 'info'
        })
        ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
            {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]},
            {test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'},
            {test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Как уменьшить размер bundle.js (или ускорить загрузку страницы на мобильном)?

Comment: Вот посмотрите здесь, но на английском. https://medium.lucaskatayama.com/reducing-bundle-js-size-from-webpack-8a9c3adbdad4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При использовании Webpack есть несколько  простых способов  значительного уменьшения размера сборки (и применять их, разумеется, можно в совокупности).

Флаг **-p**
Добавление этого флага при выполнении сборки, выполнит его в production режиме, произведя манипуляции, ведущие к уменьшению размера сборки.

`webpack --config webpack.config.js -p`

**Uglify Plugin**
В webpack есть встроенный плагин, в комплекте методов optimize, который производит множество интересных манипуляций с бандлом и кроме, собственно, аглификации и минификации умеет убирать consloe.log, комментарии и т.п.
Пример для конфигурации:

```
  plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  beautify: false,
  mangle: {
    screw_ie8: true,
    keep_fnames: true
  },
  compress: {
    screw_ie8: true,
    drop_console: true
  },
  comments: false,
})]
```

Описание (кроме процесса инсталляции, подходит для webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin):
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Уже данных манипуляций хватает, чтобы сжать стандартный стартовый 6 мегабайтный размер средненькой заготовки килобайт до 700.

Для последующей оптимизации неплохо себя зарекомендовал

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer

В графическом виде показывает кто и сколько отъедает у бандла.
Пример конигурации для webpack:

```
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-
    analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

plugins: [
   new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
  analyzerMode: 'server',
  analyzerHost: 'localhost',
  analyzerPort: 8888,
  reportFilename: 'report.html',
  defaultSizes: 'parsed',
  openAnalyzer: true,
  generateStatsFile: false,
  statsFilename: 'stats.json',
  statsOptions: null,
  logLevel: 'info'
})]
```

Comment: У меня стоит флаг NODE_ENV=production, если добавить -p, то из 6 МБ bundle выростает до 8,6 МБ. А если оставить только -p , то вообще до 9МБ )))))) Что-то не то)

Comment: Если использовать new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin то тоже вырастает до 8.6 МБ

Comment: А можно конфиг вебпака?

Comment: Добавил в описание темы

Comment: Судя по отсутствию `rules` это первый webpack?

Comment: подскажите как оптимизировать, если заметили отсутствие rules)

Comment: Так webpack то какой? Rules заменили loaders, начиная со второй версии. Это никак с оптимизацией не связано. Если навскидку, без привязки к версии, devtools в прод сборке не нужен, все что связано с  hot reload также, bundle analizer тоже там ни к чему. Сурсмап не для продакшен, у вебпаке есть отличная таблица по сурсмап https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/. По самому бандой, в аналайзере мы видим bootstrap.min.css, статика в банде выглядит так себе. Символов в комментариях ограниченное количество.

Comment: А как bootstrap.min.css вынести за бандл?

Comment: А вебпаке то всё-таки первый?

Comment: Не первый, второй)))

Comment: Тогда, как минимум, он неверно настроен. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders. Настройки loaders для 2+ вебпаков